# Displaying session state in masterpage for asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am designing a website whish has common forms such as login,logout,registration,masterpage etc.I am maintaining session when user logs in.I want to show logout on menu bar which is in master page if user is logged in else login and register new menu should be displayed.But logout menu is not shown whether user is logged in or not.Any help would be thankful.

login code:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String pass=TextBox2.Text;
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='C:\\Users\\aayush\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\WebSites\\JustDial\\App_Data\\Database.mdf';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * From shop where shop_email = @param1", con);       
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", TextBox1.Text);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {

            String pass2 = dr["shop_password"].ToString();
            if (pass.Equals(pass2))
            {
                Session["email"] = dr["shop_email"].ToString();
                Response.Redirect("home.aspx");            
            }
            else {
                TextBox1.Text = "";
                TextBox2.Text = "";
                Label1.Text = "Invalid email id or password";         
             }

        }

        dr.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

and menu bar code in master page:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href='home.aspx'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='about.aspx'><span>About</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='feedback.aspx'><span>Feedback</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='contact.aspx'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
   <%
       if (Session["email"] is bool && (bool)Session["email"])

       {%>

        <li><a href='logout.aspx'><span>Logout</span></a></li>

       <% }

       else {%>

        <li><a href='login.aspx'><span>Login</span></a></li>
     <li class='last'><a href='addShop.aspx'><span>Register</span></a></li>
       <%
       }

        %>

</ul>
```

Comment: check if you are getting value in email variable - try showing value of email to confirm the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing i would do is stop adding `<% %>` to your asp.net page.  This is something we used to do in classic ASP.  You should not need to do this very often in ASP.NET.

Wrap the `<li>` tags in a panel.

```
<asp:Panel id="pnlLogOut" runat="server">
   <li><a href='logout.aspx'><span>Logout</span></a></li>
</asp:Panel>
```

Then in your code behind you can display it.

```
if (Session["email"] is bool && (bool)Session["email"])
    pnlLogOut.Visible = true;
```

This way you can easily debug what is in your session in the code behind.

Change your if statement, Session["email"] is not a boolean.

From:

```
if (Session["email"] is bool && (bool)Session["email"])
```

To:

```
if (Session["email"] != null )
```

Comment: I added two panels one for login and other for logout and fired this code but not working :public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["email"] is bool && (bool)Session["email"])
        {
            pnlLogOut.Visible = true;
            pnlLogIn.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            pnlLogIn.Visible = true;
            pnlLogOut.Visible = false;
        }
    }
}

Comment: When you step through the code, what is in Session["email"]?  Do you have a logout button that sets Session["email"] = null?

Comment: Change your if statement.